# ForeignKey in template

Tags: django

Models:

```
class Design(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_lengt=255)

class DesignImg(models.Model):
    design = models.ForeignKey(Design)
    img = models.ImageField(upload_to="project_images")
```

views:

```
def index(request):
    d = Design.objects.all()
    return render_to_response('index.html',{'d':d},context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

templates(this is incorrect):

```
{% for a in d %}
    <img src="{{ a.img.url }}"/>
{% endfor %}
```

How to display all my `img`in template?

Comment: Where's the end of your `img` tag? Other then that your code is correct.

Comment: Maybe you need two nested loops.

Comment: @freakish: No, `img` is in `DesignImg` model not in `Design` model.

Comment: @user2659960 Ah, right. Then you have to retrieve all `DesignImg` objects (you are talking about *all* images) instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you are trying to reference a reverse foreign key,

```
{% for a in d %}
    {% for image in a.designimg_set.all %}
        <img src="{{ image.img.url }}"/>
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

You can read [more here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/topics/db/queries/#lookups-that-span-relationships)

Comment: You can read up about [`prefetch_related`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#prefetch-related) and [`select_related`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#select-related) to make it more efficient, as @freakish mentioned about efficiency.

Answer (score 0):

One of the solutions would be what @karthikr proposes. However it might no be efficient enough (many queries if many instances of `Design` in db).

Another solution would be to simply pass `DesignImg.objects.all()` to your template instead. You are trying to show all images after all.

Comment: well.. one could always use `prefetch_related` or `select_related` to make it more efficient.